# Why do I get "invalid workspace" error message using arcpy.sa.Reclassify?

Tags: spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.4, python-toolbox, error-000875

I am reclassifying a raster in a Python Toolbox as part of my workflow. When I test the code in a normal Python script (.py), my code works; however, when running in a Python Toolbox I get ERROR 000875: Invalid output workspace and ERROR 000581: Invalid parameters.

**Error Message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 122, in execute
File "c:\program files 
(x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 5753, in Reclassify missing_values)
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 5747, in Wrapper
missing_values)
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 506, in <lambda>
return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
ExecuteError: ERROR 000875: Output raster: D:\word\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\Reclass_test_1.tif's workspace is an invalid output workspace. 
ERROR 000581: Invalid parameters. 
Failed to execute (Reclassify).
```

**Codes as it looks in Python toolbox** (relevant parts only)

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName = "Input Polygon",
        name = "Input Polygon",
        datatype = ["DEFeatureClass", "DEShapefile"],
        parameterType = "Required",
        direction = "Input")
    param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName = "Choose Output Folder on your Local Drive",
        name = "Output Folder",
        datatype = "DEFolder",
        parameterType = "Required",
        direction = "Input")
    param2 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName = "Output(s) Name",
        name = "Output(s) Name",
        datatype = "GPString",
        parameterType = "Required",
        direction = "Input")
    param3 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName = "Slope Threshold",
        name = "Slope Threshold",
        datatype = "GPLong",
        parameterType = "Required",
        direction = "Input")

    params = [param0, param1, param2, param3]
    return params

def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    # Relevent paramters obtained from User
    polygon = parameters[0].value
    output_folder = parameters[1].valueAsText
    name = parameters[2].value
    slope_threshold = parameters[3].value

    # Save copy of slope raster overlapping input polygon's extent
    arcpy.Clip_management(slope_raster, "", output_folder + "/{0}_slope.tif".format(name), polygon, "", "ClippingGeometry", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")   
    # Clip slope raster using input polygon. 
    slope = arcpy.Raster(output_folder + "/{0}_slope.tif".format(name))

    # Reclassify slope
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
    remapVals = [[0, slope_threshold, 1], [slope_threshold, 99, 0]]
    remap = arcpy.sa.RemapRange(remapVals)
    outputReclass = arcpy.sa.Reclassify(slope, "VALUE", remap, "NODATA")      # Line 122 from Python Toolbox file (.pyt) causing error is .
    outputReclass.save(output_folder + "/{0}_recl.tif".format(name))     #Line 123 where I try to save output, but clearly not working
    arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial")
    return
```

**Code in normal Python file** (.py) that works fine

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
scriptpath = os.getcwd()
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')

name = "test"

slope = arcpy.Raster(scriptpath + "/test_slope.tif")

slope_threshold = 25
remap_vals = [[0, slope_threshold, 1], [slope_threshold, 99, 0]]
remap = arcpy.sa.RemapRange(remap_vals)                                         
outReclass = arcpy.sa.Reclassify(slope, "VALUE", remap, "NODATA")  
outReclass.save(scriptpath + "/{0}_recl.tif".format(name))
arcpy.CheckInExtension('Spatial')
```

**Of Note**:
If I simply omit the option of a user submitting a slope threshold, and code it like below, it works with no issues inside the Python Toolbox (code is copied & slightly altered from ArcGIS Results panel to deal with path).

```
arcpy.gp.Reclassify_sa(slope, "VALUE", "0 25 1;25 99 0", output_folder + "/{0}_recl.tif".format(name), "NODATA")
```

But if I try putting the user's slope choice back in (remap parameter)

```
arcpy.gp.Reclassify_sa(slope, "VALUE", remap, output_folder + "/{0}_recl.tif".format(name), "NODATA")
```

I get another error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 122, in execute
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 506, in <lambda>
return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```